# Displaying info from a text file in console

Tags: java, logic, text-files

I'm working on a java program that is supposed to behave like a "virtual scavenger hunt" basically it randomly goes through numbers until it hits the one that matches the animal you're looking for and then it displays the results. The info is supposed to be stored on a file and then be displayed in the console, but it just terminates as soon as I click run. I'm thinking there is some kind of logic error because I'm not getting anything regarding syntax.

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class AnimalPopulation {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int totalTrials = 0;
    int animalsSpotted = 0; 
    double randNum = 0;
    double myAnimal = 4.0;
    double notMyAnimal = 0; 
    String data = "int";

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner ("animals.txt");

    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("animals.txt"));
    //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("animals.txt"));

System.out.println("How many trials will you be running? (It must be greater than or equal to 1,000.)");
totalTrials = in.nextInt();

    while(animalsSpotted < totalTrials) {
        animalsSpotted++; 
        randNum = (1 + (Math.random()* 9));

        if(randNum < myAnimal) {

            outFile.println(notMyAnimal++);
        }else if(randNum > myAnimal) {

            outFile.println(notMyAnimal++);
        }else if(randNum == myAnimal) {

            outFile.println(myAnimal++);


            while(inFile.hasNext()) {

                data = inFile.next();
                System.out.println(data);
            }

            inFile.close();



        }


    }

outFile.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing is you have to change randNum to int and use `ThreadLocalRandom` as said in the answer, and another thing first write all the data to file then read it don't do things in parallel and here is a program for you as an example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class AnimalPopulation{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int totalTrials = 0;
    int animalsSpotted = 0;
    int randNum = 0;
    double myAnimal = 4.0;
    double notMyAnimal = 0;
    String data = "int";

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("animals.txt"));
    //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("animals.txt"));

    System.out.println("How many trials will you be running? (It must be greater than or equal to 1,000.)");
    totalTrials = in.nextInt();

    while(animalsSpotted < totalTrials) {
        animalsSpotted++;
        randNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,11);

        if(randNum < myAnimal) {

            outFile.println(notMyAnimal++);
        }else if(randNum > myAnimal) {

            outFile.println(notMyAnimal++);
        }else if(randNum == myAnimal) {

            outFile.println(myAnimal++);
        }
    }
    outFile.close();
    File file = new File("animals.txt");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String st;
    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(st);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you as well, it works now. I'm going to use this program as a reference from now on.

Comment: Nice example. Also a minor improvement is possible using try-with blocks to ensure the files are closed after use.

try (BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {             return br.readLine();
}

Taken from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 1):

randNum is `double` and `(1 + (Math.random()* 9))` produces some fractional value between 1 and 10 so it is extremely unlikely to be equal to 4.0. Instead, you may want to change the types to `int` and use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,11)` to generate a value between 1 and 10.

Comment: It says ThreadLocalRandom cannot be resolved. Is there something I need to import for this? I've never used it before.

Comment: Ah yep, u do need to `import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;` Assuming you are using Java 7 or later.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I hadn't even known about this.